# Selecting and sorting query by subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting rows from `table recipes` that have the same `id` as `table likes` column `recipe_id` AND with a specific `user_id` (1).

I want to sort/order everything by the `date` from table `likes` and not `recipes` as in my example...

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, slugged_url 
FROM recipes
WHERE id 
IN
(
    SELECT recipe_id 
    FROM likes t
    LEFT JOIN users tn ON tn.id = t.user_id
    WHERE tn.id = '1'
)
AND publish = '1' 
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Tried to put order in the sub-query but didn't work.

Comment: please post the schema of all the three tables and what is your sample input and what are you expecting.

Comment: The use of `limit` strongly suggests MySQL and not SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff, I will fix that!

Comment: The usage of `WHERE tn.id = '1'` strongly suggests mysql, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use explicit `join`s in the outer query and use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
SELECT r.name, r.slugged_url 
FROM recipes r JOIN
     likes l
     ON r.id = l.recipe_id
WHERE l.user_id = 1 AND r.publish = 1 
GROUP BY r.name, r.slugged_url 
ORDER BY MAX(l.date) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5;
```

You don't need the users table, because you are comparing to the `id` which is already in the `likes` table.

Comment: THANK YOU @GordonLinoff! I changed the "WHERE t.user_id", from your answer, to "WHERE l.user_id" and it worked perfect! Thank you again! :)